# asp mvc web api return 401 unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401

At first I'm beginner in asp. Start by asp.net tutorial to write a web api. 
after the tutorial finished (I did not add any other code) when I try to test the Api it return me **unautherize 401**.

I found the below line in my Web.config

`<authentication mode="None" />`

and in WebApiCOnfig.cs

`config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));`

how can I access to my API **without authentication**? it's a simple test and no need to any authentication

Comment: Either remove global/controller/action auth filters/attribute or use `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on intended controller or action

Comment: I comment the config.Filters @Nkosi. where should I add [AllowAnonymous]?

Comment: No it is one or the other. anyway. if using attribute you can place it either on the controller to apply to all actions in controller, or directly in the action itself for just that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on intended controller for all actions on that cotroller

```
[AllowAnonymous] // Applies to all ations
public class MyController : ApiController {
    public IHttpActionResult MyAction1() {
        //...
    }

    public IHttpActionResult MyAction2() {
        //...
    }
}
```

or only on the intended action

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    [AllowAnonymous] // Applies to only this ation
    public IHttpActionResult MyAction() {
        //...
    }

    //Still secure
    public IHttpActionResult MyAction2() {
        //...
    }
}
```

When done testing you can remove them.